# Best way to auto-start a program without using cron in Kali Sana?

Tags: kali-linux

What would be best way to start the program `Zim Desktop Wiki` when Kali Sana starts?

Note: I have made it XFCE

EDIT: have received Tumbleweed for this - wasn't sure if it couldn't be done without cron.There must be a GUI-FrontEnd or a CLI way to this!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the command to start your application as an rc.d script.

This script will automatically execute whatever application(s) you want based upon the run level.

[image]

Since this Zim Desktop Wiki Application appears to be some sort of GUI based app to manage Wikis, it would have to launch in run level 5 (or whatever is appropriate for Kali).

So, in the appropriate directory in `/etc/rc.d/xxx` put a short script that launches Zim Desktop.

That should give you the basics... Take a look at this article.  It should be quite useful going forwad.
https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts